# Reputation for editing questions

Tags: feature-request, editing

I think it could be months before people can edit questions and start fixing things like "english" instead of "English."

While the site is still new, can the rules on who can edit questions be relaxed some?

Comment: They are relaxed *somewhat*, but still only three people are currently eligible.

Comment: Actually, 4 people, because Jeff Atwood can (and does) edit them as well. But that's just nitpicking ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing that the title was misspelled on purpose to demonstrate the problem. If so, bravo, MatthewMartin!

Comment: @Vincent McNabb: Actually quite a few more, since there are at least six others who are moderators on every Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 4):

> While the site is still new, can the rules on who can edit questions be relaxed some?

The rules are already relaxed.
If you check the FAQ in Stack Overflow, you will notice that it's required to have a reputation of 500 (not 200) just to retag a question, and a reputation of 1500 to create new tags (not 150); you could not edit others' posts until you reach 2000, while on a beta site you can edit others' posts if your reputation is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

It's maddening isn't it? Especially for the type of person who would be interested in the content of this site.

In fact the title of your question is driving me crazy right now.

Comment: *In fact the title of your question is driving me crazy right now.* - ditto

Comment: This would be true for every Q&A Stack Exchange site, not only for english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Title updated. :)

Comment: @Noldorin - Damn! I've been struggling to figure what it is that everyone objects to in the Title - I've only just see your comment (that I am wasting my time)! lol